# Python VCenter API connection string

Tags: python, passwords, parameter-passing, vmware, esxi

I am writing a python script to automate deletion of svmi netapp snapshots using PySphere library.

to create a connection instance i do :

```
vc_server = pysphere.VIServer()
vc_server.connect("vc.example.com", "example.com\dd432", "password")
```

Everything works the expected way, the only question I have is there a way for me to hide the password in the script, maybe some hashing mechanism, to have that password argument do not specify the password in clear text in the script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For now i found only way to put password under file system into .cf file and restrict permissions for read on that file. Sure there should be some better way.

```
    @classmethod

    def setUpClass(cls):
    config_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "config_conn.cf")
    cls.config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    cls.config.read(config_path)

    host = cls.config.get("READ_ONLY_ENV", "host")
    user = cls.config.get("READ_ONLY_ENV", "user")
    pswd = cls.config.get("READ_ONLY_ENV", "password")

    cls.server = VIServer()
    cls.server.connect(host, user, pswd)
```